Film, mid-1980s, closing scene of woman running from house and escaping capture?
I watched this film in the mid-1980s (in Ireland) and my dad switched off the television just before it ended. It was on late-ish at night (certainly bedtime for children) and I think it was probably a sort of horror/ thriller. It certainly had a sinister edge. It was in colour, I am almost sure, and in English. 
I can remember the last scene I saw only, which was probably about five minutes before the end. 
A young woman (perhaps blond) is running from a grand, stately house, having escaped from her capture there. I think that there was a party going on in the house when she escaped. It was definitely at night and the house/ part of the house may also have been on fire. 
I’m sorry for the scant and vague details but that’s all I have. Thank you. 
ETA: forgot to say: if it helps, we had only five/ six channels in Ireland then - BBC1 and 2, UTV (an Irish version of ITV), Channel 4 (maybe), and RTE 1 and 2 (Irish television station).
ETA(2): am suspecting that the film might have been set in the 40s/ 50s in the US or Britain. But, again, can't be sure. 

Could this be the original Texas Chainsaw Massacre? At the end, Sally Hardesty escapes from the Sawyer family and runs away. Sally is blonde (this image is from early in the film; in later screenshots her hair seems to look darker)...

the Sawyer house is quite grand...

and of course there is a party (of sorts) going on at the time:

Ultimately the house does get burned down, but this happens later, in Texas Chainsaw 3D. Also, the setting is a bit later than 40s/50s, so not all your criteria are fulfilled. If this isn't your film, you could also try asking on scifi.sx - lots of horror experts are members there.
